# wso2 ESB - log all transactions in MySQL database

Tags: wso2-esb

I am very much new to ESB.
I have just created a WSDL based proxy and my applications work very well.
My problem is, I want to record all requests and responses in a MySQL database for report generation. Can somebody help me?

If php can be used in the process, that is very useful. I had some luck in RESTful cloning type of application, where I have created two sequences and one to a web program that writes GET values into a mysql database.

Thanks in advance.

Dhammika

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mediator [DBReport](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/DBReport+Mediator)
, example can be found [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+361%3a+Introduction+to+dbreport+Mediator)

here is an example:

```
<dbreport>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <password>wso2carbon</password>
            <user>wso2carbon</user>
            <url>jdbc:</url>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql>
            <![CDATA[insert into cache( value ) values (?);]]></sql>
         <parameter expression="$body" type="VARCHAR"/>
    </statement>
</dbreport>
```

**do not forget to add a driver mysql**

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but how do you pass a system value like Date or IP Address into database?